# SD Card reporting Date created in the future

Tags: sd-card, time, exfat

Recently I swapped out the SD Card on my camera for an identical replacement.
The card is formatted by the camera as exFat.

After taking a few sample shots with the new card, I inserted the card to the reader and checked it in 'Files'(Nautilus?).

It tells me the creation date is 10 hours into the future [incidentally I am at (GMT +10)]
I'm guessing that it is adding the PC timezone on top of the local time the camera created.

I've tried going into 'disks' and altering the mounting options from 'auto' to 'exfat'
I've also tried adding 'tz=UTC' and 'time_offset=-600' either together or separately but it doesn't work.

The strange thing is, it wasn't a problem for my old exfat card.

I'm running Ubuntu 22.04 with all the updates & have 'exfat-fuse' & 'exfatprogs' installed.
I'm sure it must be a setting. Currently I'm working with the defaults again.

[image]

I've unmounted and mounted the card again, restarted after changes.. nothing seems to work. I did check the metadata for an image file & the created date and time are correct and local.

Comment: Did you check the camera, that writes the time stamp, in the first place?

Comment: Hi, yes the camera is the correct time and time zone.
I even reset all the settings of the camera to make sure.

Comment: Can it be that your camera does not record time zone information in the file stamp, or is set to timezone UTC 0? Something else: the kernel now supports exfat. You may want to removing exfat-fuse and rely on the build-in kernel support for exfat instead.

Comment: I tried removing "exfat-fuse" and "exfatprogs" & following a restart... no change.
I set the camera to print a timestamp on the image to double check the date and time and it is correct. The metadata records a location, local time and a timezone of '600' that being 10 hours, so I'm sure it is functioning correctly. With the old card it did work fine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems I've partially solved it... next to 'x-gvfs-show' add 'time_offset=600'
not -600. This will fix any files created from then.

Any files on the SD Card that were accessed by the system *prior* to this mounting fix will be permanently altered by the system. Even with the fix afterwards. Hence, no matter how many fixes I tried, it would never reverse out the damage.

However, if you copy the file.. the created date is now the date you copied it, not the date and time the file was originally taken on the camera. I guess that is what metadata is for.